# modal window not modal in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm opening a modal window with javascript like this:

```
window.showModalDialog('<%=Url.Action("Index","Bank") %>', "Ratting",
            'width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,')
```

and it works properly in all browsers except **for chrome (it's not modal)**
I want to know whether is this a bug or a feature? or maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I personally think it is good that Chrome doesn't allow a webpage to open a modal window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like google doesn't care: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=184e7414aecbd346&hl=en